# How to get docker stack list through docker API

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

How we can get the stack list through docker api, I had tried the following api sources but couldn't find anything about it.

```
https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.41/#
https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/swarm.html
```

Comment: I assumed it was a case of enumerating services and looking for com.docker.stack.namespace labels.

Comment: Yes we can get list of stack from services, but then how we can delete a stack through an api call?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't an API endpoint for that directly. You can get it from the `/services` endpoint though. Here's an example using `jq`:

```sh
$: curl 127.0.0.1:2375/services | jq "[.[].Spec.Labels.\"com.docker.stack.namespace\" | select(. != null)] | unique"

[
  "stack-1",
  "stack-2"
]
```